# Menu with MooTools

Tags: ajax, joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5 and I want to modified a `<div>` tag with *ajax* and *mootools*

In my `index.php` file I have this:

```
<div id="content" class="column grid_16">
    <div id="content" class="column grid_4">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuHardware" style="none"/>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuArq" style="none"/>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="column grid_9">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_arq" style="none"/>
    </div>
    <jdoc:include type="component" />

    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_fabricante" style="none"/>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_noticias" style="none"/>
</div>
```

This is my code  in `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuArq" style="none"/>`:

```
<div id="content" class="column grid_4">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-129"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
        <li class="item-130"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
        <li class="item-131"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
        <li class="item-132"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
        <li class="item-133"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my module `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_arq" style="none"/>` have this:

```
<div id="myDivTobeChanged">some text for change</div>
```

So finally my page is:

```
<div id="content" class="column grid_16">
    <div id="content" class="column grid_4">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-129">
            <a href="/index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-130">
            <li class="item-131">
                <li class="item-132">
                    <li class="item-133">
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content" class="column grid_9">
    <div id="myDivTobeChanged">some text for change</div>
</div>
```

when I click here `<li class="item-129"><a href="/index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>` I want to change this

```
<div id="myDivTobeChanged">some text for change</div>
```

This is my script to call ajax:

```
$$('.item-129').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    var req= new Request({
        method: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php',
        data: {'do': '1'},
        onComplete: function(responseText){
            $('myDivTobeChanged').set('html', responseText);
        }
    }).send();
});
```

But this don´t work only change to description page but not inside the `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the div in your code has class 'grid_4', but the one you try to modify has 'column grid_9'. If you want to change the contents of a particular div it would be much better to refer to it by id or you will have to fetch an array of elements having particular class via `$$('.grid-9')`.

Another problem is that you mix pure JavaScript with MooTools, that is generally a bad idea. If a MooTools library provide a function to solve your problem, it is better to use it rather than standard JavaScript. For example to change HTML contents of an element, use `set('html', someHTML)` rather than `innerHTM`L method.

So, try giving your div to be changed an id and changing you line

```
document.getElementsByClassName('column grid_9').innerHTML= responseText;
```

to something like this:

```
document.id('#myDivTobeChanged').set('html', responseText);
```

This is a complete solution for illustration purposes that works. You can use it for reference:

```
//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        $$('.item-129').addEvent('click', function(event){
             event.stop();
              var req = new Request({
              method: 'get',
              url: 'http://someurl.com/test.php',
              data: { 'do' : '1' },

              onComplete: function(responseText) { 
              $('myDivTobeChanged').set('html', responseText);
              }
            }).send();
        });


    });
</script>

//sample html
<div id="content" class="column grid_4">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="item-129"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
<li class="item-130"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
<li class="item-131"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
<li class="item-132"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
<li class="item-133"><a href="index.php/descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="myDivTobeChanged">som text for change</div>
```

Just make change the address the Request is send to and customize the id of the target HTML div to be changed

Comment: thanks @akhilless I modified my code and try and change other thinks but still do the same.

Comment: You are welcome.The code has been tested. You can see it working here: http://demo-project.akhilless.c9.io/php/test.php. Try to verify what the php script called via AJAX is returning via Firebug.